# gulp, webpack-stream and webpack-5: output is memory only

Tags: webpack, gulp, webpack-5

[Community: will someone please create a [webpack-stream](/questions/tagged/webpack-stream) tag?]

I'm using gulp and webpack-stream to use webpack to build my react project into one .js file and I would like to break it down into multiple .js files.  I specifically want to use the new webpack-5 entry options "input" and "dependOn" so I can put the react framework into its own .js file and have all the other .js files depend on it, instead of having all .js files have all the react code.  I thought I had done exactly what I wanted, but then I discovered that the output files (assets) weren't actually being created.

I have distilled my gulpfile.js into a minimum example of how a gulp task compiles two of my react files with webpack-stream's default webpack-4 and creates the output, and the same gulpfile.js using webpack-5 which does NOT create the output.  (I chose to have the webpack options in the gulp file and use lodash.clonedeep, instead of having a webpack.config.js file).

gulpfile.js using webpack-4:

```
    const gulp = require('gulp');
    const cloneDeep = require('lodash.clonedeep');
    const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
    const webpack5 = require('webpack');
    
    const filePermission = "0744";
    
    const webpackOptions = {
        mode: 'production', devtool: false,
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.jsx?$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: { presets: 
                            [   '@babel/preset-react'
                            ,   '@babel/env'
                            ,   { 'plugins': ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'] }
                            ] 
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    };
    
    gulp.task('compile-react', () =>
    {
        let options = cloneDeep(webpackOptions);
        options['entry'] = {
            tabs: './javascript/react/_tabs.jsx',
            sidebar: './javascript/react/_sidebar.jsx',
        };
        options['output'] = {
            filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        };
        return webpackStream(options)
            .pipe(gulp.dest('javascript/dist', { mode: filePermission }));
    });
```

The output from running <kbd>gulp compile-react</kbd> from the CLI:

```
[09:46:32] Starting 'compile-react'...
[09:46:35] Version: webpack 4.46.0
Built at: 07/30/2021 9:46:35 AM
            Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
sidebar.bundle.js  8.78 KiB       0  [emitted]  sidebar
   tabs.bundle.js  8.58 KiB       1  [emitted]  tabs
Entrypoint tabs = tabs.bundle.js
Entrypoint sidebar = sidebar.bundle.js
[09:46:35] Finished 'compile-react' after 2.29 s
```

In the /javascript/dist/ folder I see the two assets, sidebar and tabs.bundle.js, as expected.  But if I switch to webpack-5 by adding it as an optional argument to webpack-stream, the assets are no longer created altho the output looks good.  Here is the change to the return statement in the task to use webpack-5:

```
    [...]
        return webpackStream(options, webpack5)
            .pipe(gulp.dest('javascript/dist', { mode: filePermission }));
    });
```

Here is the output from the CLI:

```
[10:03:49] Starting 'compile-react'...
[10:03:52] asset sidebar.bundle.js 2.65 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: sidebar) 1 related asset
asset tabs.bundle.js 2.64 KiB [emitted] [minimized] (name: tabs) 1 related asset
    
webpack 5.47.1 compiled successfully
[10:03:52] Finished 'compile-react' after 2.93 s
```

But of course, the assets aren't created. It seems like I'm missing a webpack-5 option to physically create the output, but if so I cannot find it.  Help!

Comment: This bug was fixed in webpack-stream v.6; I was using v.5.  https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream/issues/238

Answer (score 0):

The [bug](https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream/issues/238) was fixed in webpack-stream v.6; I was using v.5.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31436688)